# Java Scanner add optional user input prompts

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What is the way to take some parameters as optional user input using java util Scanner? Below is my code. But, for all the parameters it's blocked till the user input is entered.

I want it to continue for second parameter in cases 'when the user input is entered and then pressed enter key' "OR" 'when just pressed enter key without entering any input'.

```
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter ordertypes in comma separated format (mandatory): " );
        String orderOrActionTypes = in.next();

        System.out.println("Enter orderAttributes (optional): " );
        String orderAttributes = in.next();

        System.out.println("Enter ActionAttributes (optional): " );
        String actionAttributes = in.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still let the input but leave it empty.
When an input is required, the user can press `Enter` (which results on an empty string), and then you can test, whether the user typed something or not `orderAttributes.isEmpty()` and you do what you need based on the results.

Comment: No, pressing enter will not help as it does not continue, it gets blocked till the user input is entered.

Comment: That's cuz you are using `in.next()`, try using `in.nextLine()` which will produce empty string when you press `Enter`

Comment: in.nextLine() will produce empty string even if there is any value entered. I want to capture the value if entered and empty string if not entered.

Comment: You should change all inputs to `in.nextLine()`, cuz `in.next()` read until it meets a space, otherwise your first input will ruin your next inputs. Change everything to `in.nextLine()` and it should work.

Comment: Glad to help, i'de appreciate un Up vote, good luck.

Comment: Sure, Thanks! I do not have enough reputation points to upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in.nextLine();`, it may help.